# Need help understanding output of a periodogram

Tags: time-series, fourier-transform, acf-pacf

In my effort to understand the output of a periodogram I created a series (s) where 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,10 is repeated 100 times and then created a periodogram of this series using the following R code:

```
library("TSA")
s=rep(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,10), times = 100) 
p=TSA::periodogram(s)
plot(p)
```

The top 5 frequencies, represented by the spikes, are: 10.00, 5.00, 3.33, 2.50, and 2.00.
[image]

I understand the value 10.00 (1 / 0.1) as that was the obvious and intentional periodicity of the series I created.
Given the series I created, I was expecting a single spike of 10.00.
What do these other peaks (5.00, 3.33, 2.50, and 2.00) represent?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Your series has more periods than just $10:$ every multiple of $10$ is also a period.

Comment: @whuber Would you elaborate on that a bit as I'm not quite sure I understand? This series has 1000 points where all values (except multiples of 10) are 1 and every 10th is a 10. Are you saying that in addition to the periodicity of 10 there is also a periodicity/repetition at 20, 40 60, etc and 30, 60, 90, etc?

Comment: Yes, by definition: if a series repeats every 10, then it repeats every 10, every 20, every 30, etc.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, that makes sense. Another question - does the periodogram say anything about where in the series a given cycle of 10, 20, etc starts and/or ends? For example, for a cycle of 10 is the periodogram saying that a) the cycle starts at position 1 and at every 10 points there is a value denoting a cyclic point or b) that the cycle is the repetition of 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,10 ?

Comment: Periods don't "know" anything about a "start."  After all, how could you formulate a universal definition of what it means to "begin" a period?  It's just like looking at paisley wallpaper: although it obviously repeats its pattern (in two separate dimensions), there is no unique way to identify what its fundamental domain is.  Escher exploited this ambiguity extensively in his woodcuts.

Comment: @whuber  Re where a cycle "starts". In the above periodogram the value of .1 indicates a periodicity of 10. Which, it seems to me and I certainly may not understand, that there is something that happens every 10 units/increments of the x-axis. Is that correct? If it is then where is the first value which "anchors" the 10 period periodicity? Am I off base here?  Thanks

Comment: There is no "anchor."  You may identify literally any point on the x-axis as the start without changing the periodicity at all.  It's like trying to find the beginning of the waves rolling in to shore from the ocean.  You could declare a particular trough, or a peak, or some other identifiable part of one wave as the "start," but that would merely be a conventoin: it wouldn't have any intrinsic meaning.

Comment: @whuber Very interesting - thanks for the explanation. So, if a periodogram indicates, for example, 2 periods (p1, p2) and I select a position on the x-axis (x1) what should I assume about the y values at points x1+p1, x1+2*p1, etc? Does this periodicity of p1 tell me that I should expect the same y value at multiples of p1 at any starting point on the x-axis? Thanks

Comment: That's the very definition of periodicity.  Here's a rigorous general statement: let $(G,+)$ be a commutative group (such as the additive real numbers).  A nonzero quantity $T \in G$ is a *period* of a function $f:G\to Y$ (where $Y$ is any set whatsoever) provided that for all $x\in G,$ $f(x+T)=f(x).$ One implication is that for any natural number $n$ we may define $0T=0\in G,$ $nT=(n-1)T+T$ for $n\gt 0,$ and $nT=-n(-T)$ for $n\lt 0;$ and we find inductively that every $nT$ is a period (for $n\ne 0$) whenever $T$ is a period.